# Getting Trends from Twitter using Oauth with application credentials, no specific twitter user

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter, oauth

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but it seems almost all answers on SO are relating to the Twitter API 1.0 and not the newer 1.1 using REST and OAuth.

I need to be able to access the latest twitter trends for specific countries, and for global, so I know our URL (for global in this case) will be:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1&exclude=hashtags
```

... and replacing "1" with location ID's based on Yahoo's WOEID.  Pretty straightforward.

Where I'm getting lost is, we want to do this at an application level at a regular interval, for instance get the current trends for Canada every N hours.  There wont be a user logged in as this would be a maintenance script called via CRON, so the whole "redirect" process is throwing me off.

How can my application get these trends without requiring specific user authorization to get a "token"?

Or is there a way to create a serialized token from our registered application in twitters API area.... or is this even possible, are we breaking some sort of Terms of Use provision in attempting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came upon what I was looking for, the "Application Only" access is done in quite a different way, I just wasn't searching for the right terms to get what I was looking for, here's the page describing all the steps necessary to get a "Bearer" token which can be used to poll Twitter without any traditional user credentials...

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth
```

Hope that helps someone else find it faster.